# Problems with routing using the ViewComponent class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I am writing a project called Social Network. It's ASP.NET Core Web Application + template Web Application (Model-View-Controller).

I added functionality, in which if the user is authorized, then he will have a "logout" field, if not logged in - "login" on the page `"_Layout.cshtml"`. For this, I used ViewComponent.

But routing is not working properly.
When I click on "Login", I will be redirected to `".../Account/~/Account/Login"`, instead of `".../~/Account/Login"`, as shown in the screenshot below.

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Part of the file `"_Layout.cshtml"`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="~/Home/Index" class="navbar-brand">My page</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Users" class="navbar-brand">Users</a></li>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("MenuParts")
    <li><a href="~/Account/Register" class="navbar-brand">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

Routing in the file "Startup.cs":

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{login?}");
});
```

MenuPartsViewComponent.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents;

namespace SocialNetwork.Components
{
    public class MenuPartsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == null)
            {
                return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(
                    new HtmlString(@"<li><a href=""~/Account/Login"" class=""navbar-brand"">Login</a></li>"));
            }
            else
            {
                return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(
                    new HtmlString(@"<li><a href=""~/Account/Logout"" class=""navbar-brand"">Logout</a></li>"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anton Belesky, You had also problem in the `<li><a href="~/Account/Register" class="navbar-brand">Register</a></li>` line and that's why I started answer with this. By the both answer solved your problem.

Comment: @TanvirArjel the links in the *_Layout* with `~` will work as expected. The view engine will render the correct URLs. The issue there would be that they are hard coded and does not use the routing table.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you so much! Yes! You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that in your cshtml, the tilde  `~` is transformed when the view is being rendered. In the `ViewComponent` however, that is not the case as you are responsible for generating the view related information.

Use the [ViewComponent.Url Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponent.url?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewComponent_Url) to generated the desired Urls instead of hard-coding them

```
public class MenuPartsViewComponent : ViewComponent {
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke() {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == null) {
            var login = Url.Action("Login", "Account");
            var html = @"<li><a href=""{0}"" class=""navbar-brand"">Login</a></li>";
            return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(
                new HtmlString(string.Format(html, login))
            );
        } else {
            var logout = Url.Action("Logout", "Account");
            var html = @"<li><a href=""{0}"" class=""navbar-brand"">Logout</a></li>";
            return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(
                new HtmlString(string.Format(html, logout))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your `href` attribute value. Remove the `~` from your all `href` of `<a>` tags and write as follows:

```
return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(
                new HtmlString(@"<li><a href=""/Account/Login"" class=""navbar-brand"">Login</a></li>"));
```